# find start and end date of previous 12 month from current date in python

Tags: python, pandas

**I need to find the start and end date of the previous 12 months from the current date.**

If the current date is **05-May-2022**

Then, it should **display past 12 months first date and last date** for all months including **current month**.

how to achieve this as each month have a different number of days? Do we have any function in datetime to achieve this?

code only display previous month first and last date, so i want to **print previous 12 months**

```
     from datetime import date, timedelta
     this_first = date.today().replace(day=1)
     prev_last = this_first - timedelta(days=1)
     prev_first = prev_last.replace(day=1)
     prev_first, prev_last
```

Output:

```
     (datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 31))
```

Expected Output:

```
     [('2021-06-01', '2021-06-30'), ('2021-07-01', '2021-07-31'), 
      ('2021-08-01', '2021-08-31'), ('2021-09-01', '2021-09-30'), 
      ('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31'), ('2021-11-01', '2021-11-30'), 
      ('2021-12-01', '2021-12-31'), ('2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'), 
      ('2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'), ('2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'), 
      ('2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'), ('2022-05-01', '2022-05-31')]
```

Note:
dtype should be only in datetime.

Comment: you could get `month` and use `month-12` with `.replace()` like `your_date.replace(month=month-12, day=1)`, `your_date.replace(month=month-11, day=1) - timedelta(day=1)`

Comment: please send code for better understanding. or any changes that i should make in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `current_date.replace(day=1)` to get first day in current month.
And if you substract `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` then you get last day in previous month.
And you can use again `replace(day=1)` to get first day in previous month.

If you repeate it in loop then you can get first day and last day for all 12 months.

```
import datetime

current = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 5)

start = current.replace(day=1)

for x in range(1, 13):
    end   = start - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    start = end.replace(day=1)
    print(f'{x:2} |', start.date(), '|', end.date())
```

Result:

```
 1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30
 2 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31
 3 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28
 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31
 5 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-31
 6 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30
 7 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-31
 8 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-30
 9 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31
10 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-31
11 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-30
12 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-31
```

---

**EDIT:**

And if you use pandas then you can use `pd.date_range()` but it can't for previous dates so you would have to first get `'2021.04.05'` (for `MS`) and `'2021.05.05'` (for `M`)

```
import pandas as pd

#all_starts = pd.date_range('2021.04.05', '2022.04.05', freq='MS')
all_starts   = pd.date_range('2021.04.05', periods=12, freq='MS')
print(all_starts)

#all_ends   = pd.date_range('2021.05.05', '2022.05.05', freq='M')
all_ends   = pd.date_range('2021.05.05', periods=12, freq='M')

print(all_ends)

for start, end in zip(all_starts, all_ends):
    print(start.to_pydatetime().date(), '|', end.to_pydatetime().date())
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01',
               '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01',
               '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')

DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-31', '2021-06-30', '2021-07-31', '2021-08-31',
               '2021-09-30', '2021-10-31', '2021-11-30', '2021-12-31',
               '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

2021-05-01 | 2021-05-31
2021-06-01 | 2021-06-30
2021-07-01 | 2021-07-31
2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31
2021-09-01 | 2021-09-30
2021-10-01 | 2021-10-31
2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30
2021-12-01 | 2021-12-31
2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31
2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28
2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31
2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found out that standard module [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) can gives number of days and weeks in month.

```
weeks, days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
```

Working example:

```
import calendar

year  = 2022
month = 5

for number in range(1, 13):
    if month > 1:
        month -= 1
    else:
        month = 12
        year -= 1
        
    weeks, days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)

    print(f'{number:2} | {year}.{month:02}.01 | {year}.{month:02}.{days}')
```

Result:

```
 1 | 2022.04.01 | 2022.04.30
 2 | 2022.03.01 | 2022.03.31
 3 | 2022.02.01 | 2022.02.28
 4 | 2022.01.01 | 2022.01.31
 5 | 2021.12.01 | 2021.12.31
 6 | 2021.11.01 | 2021.11.30
 7 | 2021.10.01 | 2021.10.31
 8 | 2021.09.01 | 2021.09.30
 9 | 2021.08.01 | 2021.08.31
10 | 2021.07.01 | 2021.07.31
11 | 2021.06.01 | 2021.06.30
12 | 2021.05.01 | 2021.05.31
```

Comment: what if i have to display previous 12 months last date only, from current month how is that possible. What changes i have to make in the code?

Comment: remove this value from `print()` - that's all. Most versions needs `start day` to calculate `end day` and you can't remove it from code.